# PHP 2 arrays using one to chose from the other

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am new to php and my problem is i have 2 arrays the first one is from another page via post and read into an array via post_get

```
Array (

[0] => 93
[1] => 25
[2] => 5
[3] => 4
[4] => 36
)
```

and my second array looks like this

```
Array (

[25] => Estonia
[20] => France
[4] => Germany
[5] => Greece
[75] => Hungary
[93] => India
[36] => Italy
)
```

what i want to do is if the array looks like the first one then it uses the numbers from the array and with the help from the second array makes a new array that only contains

```
Array (

[0] => India
[1] => Estonia
[2] => Greece
[3] => Germany
[4] => Italy

)
```

and using this doesn't work

```
$group is the first array
$array is the one with the country names 

foreach ($group as $value) {
if (in_array($value, $array)) {
}
else {
echo "The group ".$value." does not exist";

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this many ways. Here is a simple one:

```
$new = [];
foreach ($group as $groupId) {
    if (isset($array[$groupId])) {
        $new[] = $array[$groupId];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this.  Flip `$group` and find the key intersection with `$array`:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($group));
```

That will retain the keys, so if you want to re-index:

```
$result = array_values(array_intersect_key($array2, array_flip($array1)));
```

Comment: array function incantation one liners

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `in_array` just add some `if` checking and two `foreach` loops and use the key of the first array to the index of the second one.

Idea:

```
$array3 = array();
foreach($array1 as $key) {
    if(isset($array2[$key])) { // add some checking just so make sure no undefined indices
        $array3[] = $array2[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, almost identical and at the exact same time. Great minds think alike, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution using `array_map` function:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) use($array){ 
    return isset($array[$v])? $array[$v] : $v;    
}, $group);
```